# show a page if user is logged in web application

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, web

I used google plus service for logging to my web app (using their html button), and saving it to my DB by passing it in ajax to my server.

Now, I want to build a **different** page that a user is able to post images and descriptions but I need to know which user posted that information.

How can I do that?

Comment: first of all refer official documentation of Google Plus Service,you will find all your answers even more than that which may help you in future.

Answer (score 0):

Save the user Auth token (or whatever you're identifying the user with) in localstorage on the client-side and send it within your ajax call; and validate it on the server-side.